# insert product and upload file work separately but not together in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am developing my first CRUD test app.

I have a form with typical product name, price... and an input file to upload the product.

I created an event handler method for the change event of the form. Works fine.

I created this uploadFile() method, which works fine.

**upload-file-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute,Params} from '@angular/router';

import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {_GLOBAL} from './global.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Producto} from '../models/Producto.model';


 @Injectable()

export class UploadFileService
{
    public url:string;
    public filesToUpload:Array<File>;

    constructor()
    {
        this.url=_GLOBAL.url;//this has the URL of the REST service
        this.filesToUpload=[];
    }


    uploadFile(url:string, params:Array<string>,filesToUpload:Array<File>)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        var formData:any= new FormData();

        var asyncRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();

        for(var i=0; i<filesToUpload.length;++i)
        {
             formData.append('filesUploaded[]',filesToUpload[i],filesToUpload[i].name);
        }

        asyncRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(asyncRequest.readyState==4){
                if(asyncRequest.status==200){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(asyncRequest.response));
                }else{
                    reject(asyncRequest.response);
                }
            }
        }

        asyncRequest.open('POST',url,true);

        asyncRequest.send(formData);
   });
}



fileChangeEvent(ElementObjectReferenceWhichTriggersEvent:any)// in this case, the input type="file"
{
    this.filesToUpload=<Array<File>>ElementObjectReferenceWhichTriggersEvent.target.files;//captura los archivos mandados en el input

    console.log(ElementObjectReferenceWhichTriggersEvent.target);

    console.log(ElementObjectReferenceWhichTriggersEvent.target.files[0]);

    console.log(this.filesToUpload);

   // return this.filesToUpload;
}
```

}

And this service

**create-product.service.ts**

On this one I have the `createProduct()` method, which calls the uploadFile() method from the service above and the `http.post()` from the HTTP service.

Problem is, both methods work fine separately, but not together.

I mean, when I make this on this service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute,Params} from '@angular/router';

import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {_GLOBAL} from './global.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Producto} from '../models/Producto.model';
import {UploadFileService} from './upload-file.service';


@Injectable()

export class CreateProductService{

    public url:string;
    public errorMessage:string;
    public productToInsert:Producto;
    public imageData:string;
  
    constructor(
                    private _http:Http,
                    private _route:ActivatedRoute, 
                    private _router:Router,
                    private _uploadFile:UploadFileService
               )
    {
   
   
        this.url=_GLOBAL.url;
        this.errorMessage="";
  
        this.productToInsert=new Producto("","","","");
  
    }//end constructor


    ngOnInit()
    {


    }


    createProduct()
    {
    
    

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }
  
   
        this._uploadFile.uploadFile(`${this.url}/upload-file`,[],this._uploadFile.filesToUpload).then(

            (result)=>{
                console.log(result["complete_name"]);
            },
            (error)=>
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );

        //file is successfully uploaded, then I insert the product:

        this._http.post(`${this.url}/crear-producto`,this.productToInsert,options).pipe(
            map(
                    
                   (res)=>{
    
                       console.log ("res del callback del map" + res);
                       
                       return res.json();
    
                    },(err)=>{
    
                         return err;
    
                    }
                
                
                )
                   
    
    
            ) .subscribe(
    
                (response)=>
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    this._router.navigate(['all-products']);
                  
    
                },
                (error)=>
                {
                     console.log(error);

                }
    
            );



}
```

}

It works: file is uploaded and product is correctly inserted... Problem is, on database I want the `result["complete_name"]` to be stored on the image field, then I can show the image later when I get all the products, instead of the "c:/fakepath/PICTURE.PNG" included on the field by the `http.post()`

For that, I need to capture the response and then change the object productToInsert.imagen with the `result["complete_name"]`

To do that, I used the `http.post()` only when the promise response was successful. So, when the image is uploaded, I capture the response result, add it to the object passed as parameter on the post() method, and send it.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute,Params} from '@angular/router';

import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {_GLOBAL} from './global.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Producto} from '../models/Producto.model';
import {UploadFileService} from './upload-file.service';


@Injectable()

export class CreateProductService{

    public url:string;
    public errorMessage:string;
    public productToInsert:Producto;
    public imageData:string;

    constructor(
                    private _http:Http,
                    private _route:ActivatedRoute, 
                    private _router:Router,
                    private _uploadFile:UploadFileService
                )
    {
   
   
        this.url=_GLOBAL.url;
        this.errorMessage="";
  
        this.productToInsert=new Producto("","","","");
  
    }//end constructor


    ngOnInit()
    {


    }

 
    createProduct()
    {
    
    

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this._uploadFile.uploadFile(`${this.url}/upload-file`,[],this._uploadFile.filesToUpload).then(

        (result)=>{
            console.log(result["complete_name"]);
            this.productToInsert.imagen=result["complete_name"];


            this._http.post(`${this.url}/crear-producto`,this.productToInsert,options).pipe(
        
        
                map(
                    
                    (res)=>{
                               return res.json();
    
                    },(err)=>{
    
                               return err;
    
                    }
                
                
                )).subscribe(

                    (response)=>
                    {
                        console.log( response);
                        this._router.navigate(['all-products']);
                  
    
                    },
                    (error)=>
                    {
                        console.log(+error);
                   
                     }
    
                );

            },
            (error)=>{
                console.log(error);

            }

       );
   }

}
```

But that doesn´t work. I get a 200 response, but the object in this case seems to be empty (null on all fields), instead of the ones coming from the form.

Here is the form used

**create-product-component.html**

```
<form #formCreateProduct="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="_createProduct.createProduct();  formCreateProduct.reset()" class="col-lg-6" id="form-crear-producto-id">

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="nombreLabel"> Name of the new product:
   
            <span *ngIf="!nombre.valid && nombre.touched && _createProduct.productToInsert.nombre.length != 0" class="label label-danger">Minimun 3 characters please</span>

        </label>  

  
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" #nombre="ngModel" pattern =".{3,}"[(ngModel)]="_createProduct.productToInsert.nombre" required /> <br/>



    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="priceLabel">Price ( € ): (please decimals with a dot. Ex:29.5)

            <span *ngIf="!precio.valid && precio.touched && _createProduct.productToInsert.precio.length != 0" class="label label-danger">Price is not valid. At least one number please, and only numbers</span>

       </label>

       <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="price" #precio="ngModel" pattern="[0-9.]+" [(ngModel)]="_createProduct.productToInsert.precio" required />  <br/>


    </div>


    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="imageLabel">Image:</label>

         <!--file doesnt suport the ngmodel-->
            <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="imagen" (change)="_uploadFile.fileChangeEvent($event)" [(ngModel)]="_createProduct.productToInsert.imagen" required /> <br/>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="descriptionLabel">Description:</label>

        <div [ngClass]="{'TopLength': _createProduct.productToInsert.descripcion.length==300}">{{_createProduct.productToInsert.descripcion.length}}/300</div>

           <textarea name="description" class="form-control" maxlength="300" #descripcion="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="_createProduct.productToInsert.descripcion" cols="40" rows="3" ></textarea> <br/>


     </div>
  
  
  
     <input type="submit" value={{title}}  [disabled]="formCreateProduct.invalid" class ="btn btn-lg btn-success" /> <br/>

</form>
```

I know, since it is my first app with angular, services and such things are maybe a bit weird used, but I tried:

- to avoid services and put them directly in component.ts
- Use only a service for create-component-service.ts, put there all methods (uploadFile, eventHandler, createProduct), and using them on component (which I guess is actually the correct way of using the service).
- to bind the "this" scope to see if there could be any problem with the scope inside the arrow function.

But nothing works. I don´t know why I can access and correctly use the object and both methods when I use them separately, but I find this problem when using this way together, which is what the teacher told us to do.

A tip that maybe useful for you, is that somewhere I get an error (among others lol), but I must say this error and the others give me no problem to upload File and createproduct on a separate way, so I planned to debug them later.

```
Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: The operation is insecure. ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js/DefaultDomRenderer2.prototype.setProperty@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56793:9 ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/DebugRenderer2.prototype.setProperty@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42592:9 ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js/DefaultValueAccessor.prototype.writeValue@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:48231:9 setUpModelChangePipeline/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49205:9 ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js/FormControl.prototype.setValue/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:50262:65 ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js/FormControl.prototype.setValue@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:50262:13 ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js/NgModel.prototype._updateValue/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51617:46 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2710:17 onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35055:24 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2709:17 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2460:24 scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3194:29 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:17 onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35046:24 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:17 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:28 drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2917:25 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2822:21 invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:9 globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was a dummy thing:

Problem was, in my component, from previous versions, I had, on the form:

`<form #formCreateProduct="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="_createProduct.createProduct();formCreateProduct.reset()" class="col-lg-6" id="form-crear-producto-id">`

The reset() method was setting all form values to null before I actually send them. Removed this method (on new version I make a redirection so I don´t need it), and problem solved. 2 days for this... :O